# No access to review queues?

Tags: support, review

When I click on the review queue button, it shows

> There are no review queues available to you

I previously had access and I am wondering if this is just saying that there are no queues that need to be reviewed or if it's a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it may be caused by having used up all your up/down votes for the day—you've cast 40. See here: [Review queues seem to have disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305411/152515)

So it's not exactly a bug, but it certainly isn't an ideal user experience.

You have enough reputation for the [Access Review Queues privilege](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) (500+) which means you should be able to see the Late Answers and First Posts review queue otherwise. You are also not review banned [which caused this issue for someone else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293479/152515).